# Is there a way to see every single thing that is happening, in the Console tab?

Tags: javascript, firebug

For example, if there is a slideshow moving along, I can see the HTML changing live in Firebug's `HTML` tab.

The `Console` tab only shows things that are console.log()-ged to it, or if there is an error. I would like to see confirmation that each line of the Javascript is getting executed - as well as any output/values that are returned/generated as that happens. Like a little cursor on the left going down line by line as it executes - and stopping as soon as error is encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use breaking points and debugging in console. You can open your script in firebug and choose lines where you can add breakpoints. Then, you can run your script and see in panel on the right a lot of stuff.